# Invert the order of a string, while preserving the original contents of the string

Tags: python, string, reverse

So I'm trying to reverse a string `31/12/9999` to `9999/12/31`, I've been trying `date = date[::-1]` but it produces `9999/21/31` and doesn't preserve the contents of the string.

I'm kind of looking for something similar to the `php`, `reverse_array( $array , $preserve );`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split it into a list with [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), then print the reversed string with [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> s = "31/12/9999"
>>> L = s.split('/') # L now contains ['31', '12', '9999']
>>> print '/'.join(L[::-1]) # Reverse the list, then print all the content in the list joined by a /
9999/12/31
```

Or, in one line:

```
>>> print '/'.join(s.split('/')[::-1])
```

However, if you're working with dates, you should use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module so you can do other stuff later with the dates:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = "31/12/9999"
>>> date = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%d/%m/%Y')
>>> print date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
9999/12/31
```

---

Timing comparisons:

```
$ python -m timeit 's = "31/12/9999"' "'/'.join(s.split('/')[::-1])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.799 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 's = "31/12/9999"' "'/'.join(reversed(s.split('/')))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how to do it with Python

```
 '/'.join(reversed(s.split('/')))
 9999/12/31
```